# How do I embed a Facebook pixel inside a spotify widget?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, pixel

I'm trying to get this running so that I can run effective conversion ads targetted at getting more Spotify followers as an independent musician, but I'm pretty stuck on the code and would really appreciate any help.

Here's the code to embed the widget:

```html
<iframe src="[https://open.spotify.com/follow/1/?uri=spotify:artist:2azZ42vFLPnhiQVjgJBKjy&size=detail&theme=light](https://open.spotify.com/follow/1/?uri=spotify:artist:2azZ42vFLPnhiQVjgJBKjy&size=detail&theme=light)" width="300" height="56" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I can see on Facebooks tools for developers website they have a code template for adding a Facebook pixel trigger when a button is clicked.

```
<!-- Somewhere there is a button that performs Add to Cart --> <button id="addToCartButton">Add To Cart</button> <!-- Add Pixel Events to the button's click handler --> <script type="text/javascript"> var button = document.getElementById('addToCartButton'); button.addEventListener( 'click', function() { fbq('track', 'AddToCart', { content\_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes', content\_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes', content\_ids: \['1234'\], content\_type: 'product', value: 4.99, currency: 'USD' }); }, false ); </script>
```

I've used inspect page elements to find out that the button ID is "Follow on Spotify". But changing the button ID to this in the code still doesn't work and all it will do is either show the code in plain text or say script disabled. Would really appreciate any help in figuring this out.

Comment: You won't be able to do this. The iframe is protected from your code.

Comment: It seems like there's an issue with your iframe link, also.

Comment: The iframe seems to be working on the website https://www.senseoffence.com/blog/listen-to-dark-thoughts

Comment: that's a shame, is there no way I could insert the pixel code inside the iframe?

Comment: @SamTucker There is not, no.